# How to calculate in Branch Testing?

Tags: manual-testing

I wants to need the procedure about how to calculate branch testing.

If i wants to make test case for it, how to create for it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question needs more background information. What are you looking to do exactly? And what have you explored so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by calculate branch testing? 
Are you looking for an answer to how to find out the number of branches in the software? Or is it about the test coverage?
If it is about the latter you must first find out the number of decisions in the module's code. Then prepare a checklist of it for testing. Once you are done with testing look into the code once again to check if you have missed anything.

Comment: If i wants to make test case for it, how i will create for it?

Comment: Hello Parag, according to you what is a test case? How have you been deriving it till now? What oracles or basis have you been using to derive your cases? How do you document them?

Comment: When i am going for interview last 3 days before, they ask me about this, they give me one branch example and tell me to write down testcase for that. How can i do for this?

Comment: All you have to do is to gather as much information about the module you are given. Then think of all the scenarios you can to test it. Once you are done with that you can make a checklist for it or use uml or mindmap it or narrate a story of the tests you are going to perform. But the best way to write test cases is to ask the devs designers and the superiors that how would they like to get that information? In what format would the like to have it and what details would they like to read in it. Ask your customers(devs designers analysts etc) about the delivery of your product(test report)...

Comment: Nice Milin, and and reference site or material available for this type?

Comment: I do not have any specific site in mind. But there are a lot of blogs about gathering testing documentation. You can try googling it. But i would suggest you ask yo ur developer friends about what information will help them identify and resolve a bug and how would they like that information delivered. Practice it as much as you can and improve on it everyday. That is how i learned it!

Answer (score 1):

For practical purposes, I use [McCabe Cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) to estimate the number of tests required for thorough branch testing. This this actually gives a good number for "basis path testing". The linked article gives a good explaination about the differences.
   McCabe Cyclomatic complexity is a practical measure because there are many tools that will automatically calculate this for you.

If you are researching for an exam and need the precise calculation for branch coverage, [here is a good resource](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/software_testing_dictionary/branch_testing.htm) that shows the procedure.

Good luck!

John

Comment: How to create test case for this?